# Why not getting response from one URL?

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am using `URLSession`. I am not receiving any error or response.

It works with one url. However it does not work with one another.

I have also tried `percentencoding`. But it doesn't work too.

The code is below

```
let urlString = "https://stark-spire-93433.herokuapp.com/json"//This is not working
//let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"//This is working
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)//URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [], options: [])
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    print("response---",response)
    print("error--",error)
    if data != nil {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
        print("JSOn",json)

    } else {
        print("error data is nil")
    }

})
task.resume()
```

Comment: Its not url its a json

Comment: @wings any suggestion please ? I am looking for getting that json into my app.

Comment: Why do you set the httpBody?

Comment: @Larme updated !

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. It might be a network issue on your side.

Comment: @Larme it was the `httpBody` issue thanks for suggesting. I am reverting my original question,

Comment: @MohammadRezaFarahani after removing httpBody it works

Comment: @Amit... you can also try Jaydeep answer

Answer (score 2):

Too cumbersome code.

This is sufficient

```
let url = URL(string:"https://stark-spire-93433.herokuapp.com/json")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else { print(error!); return }
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        print("JSOn",json)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```